# Rails Web App. Help display OpenWeather API icons or json on home page

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm trying to simply make a third party api call to Open Weather and display the result on the home page of my web app. I am able to successfully make the request in my console by running the file but I cannot get it to show up on my view file. Oddly enough I cannot find anything about actually displaying the returned json in ruby on rails.

```
<h1 class="hello"><%= @weather.posts %></h1>
```

The index.html (home)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'


class Weather
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'http://https://api.openweathermap.org/'

  def posts
    self.class.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Memphis&appid=36197f2c3289996e0f0fd7a5ef7d851c')
  end
end

@weather = Weather.new
puts @weather.posts
```

The .rb model

```
class WeatherController < ActionController::Base

response = HTTParty.get('http://https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Memphis&appid=36197f2c3289996e0f0fd7a5ef7d851c')
JSON.parse response, symbolize_names: true
end
```

The Controller

So when I start up the server I basically get a blank where the weather icon or json should be. No errors, just blank. Considering how little I could find, it seems this might be helpful to others if answered clearly. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The code in your controller does not look correct. I guess you want to have something like:

```rb
class WeatherController < ActionController::Base

  def index
    @weather = Weather.new
  end

end
```